# Rxjs: how to switch from one observable to another mid stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

At the moment, I'm just trying to achieve the following: 
- I have an text input field and a button. When the button is clicked get the value from the input (via rxjs).

Below is what I have setup. Currently have an Observable of the button click and I have the input text field currently updating a BehaviorSubject. What I'm struggling to execute or get my head around is, when a value is emitted to the click stream to then 'switch' to the Input stream so that is what is passed to a subscription is the input value.

Currently the value being passed to the subscription is always of BehaviorSubject type (originally Observable when I wasn't using a BS).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-global-dashboard',
  template: `
     <input type="text" name="" id="new-country-input" 
     (keyup)="countryInput$.next($event.target.value)">
     <button (click)="handleAddCountryClick()" id="add-country">Add 
     country</button>

     <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let tile of tiles">
       {{tile.name}}
      </li>
     </ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./global-dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class GlobalDashboardComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit 
{

   public countryInput = '';
   public countryInput$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
   public tiles: object[];

   constructor(private http: Http) {
     this.tiles = [];
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {

      const button = document.querySelector('#add-country');
      const addClick$ = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

      const inputAfterClick$ = addClick$
         .map(() => this.countryInput$);

      inputAfterClick$.subscribe((country) => {
         console.log('country', country); // < This is always BS type rather than the underlying string
         this.doRequest(country);
      });
  }
```

Comment: You probably want something like `addClick$.map((x) => new-country-input.text).subscribe(this.countryInput$)` and then `this.countryInput$.Subscribe((country) => { })`. I'm not a rxjs developer so my syntax is a big loose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change map to flatMap

```
  const inputAfterClick$ = addClick$
     .flatMap(() => this.countryInput$);
```

Comment: `flatMap` has been deprecated. Use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) or `mergeMap`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `BehaviouralSubject`, then all you need to get is the current value of the subject. There is no need to switch the stream:

```js
const addClick$ = Observable.fromEvent(button, 'click');

addClick$.subscribe(()=>{
    //this will give you the current value of your behavioural subject
    console.log(this.countryInput$.value);
})
```

If you want to get the value of the input in a more "reactive" manner, it is better for you to use the [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Thanks, but using value or getValue() isn't the best approach. These are escape hatches - as described by the Rxjs team's

Comment: @Rich neither is using `BehaviourSubject` to store the value of an input the best approach. I am simply telling you the most optimal solution based on your question. Like I said, use reactive forms.